# Terminate ruby script on infinite loops

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i want a ruby script to terminate on infinite loops OR if a ruby script takes more than 10 seconds than terminate the script itself. I know using ctrl key or any keyboard interruption i can do so , but i want the script to terminate automatically by itself if it takes more than 10 seconds

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
require "timeout"
Timeout.timeout(10) do
  loop do
    ...
  end
end
```